# which linux distros that do not use Cinnamon DE use Nemo by default

Tags: debian, desktop-environment, distributions, nemo

I know that Ubuntu Budgie use Nemo file manager by default. Is there any other Linux Distribution which do not use Cinnamon but Nemo?

Comment: Is it possible to just install `nemo`? I ask because this is not really an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: I am a novice user. Previously I tried to install different file managers and it did not end well for me. Even a different torrent client created problem for me. So, I like my GUI stuff prebuild with the distro.

Comment: The best way to have nemo as default is to use a distro that comes with cinnamon as the default desktop environment. Fedora has a spin with it, Debian can come with it, and of course Linux Mint by default uses cinnamon. Beyond that, you need to install it yourself. Everyone was a beginner at one point and without pushing outside your comfort zone and breaking things from time to time you will never learn how to change defaults or install new programs in Linux. At least you have the option when you use a Linux OS.

Comment: I know it is not appropriate to say thanks in this site, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy to tell exactly what distro use by default nemo. because those kind of applications are not a part of a the core system.

What you can do instead is check what distro have the nemo package available. (and thus you could replace the default file explorer).

You can search for the nemo package on different distro [here](https://pkgs.org/download/nemo) or [here](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages)